# libgwt-dev-java package and GWT Compiler

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-compiler

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to compile a GWT application. I'm getting this error:

> Unable to initialize cache. Couldn't create directory /home/myUser/workspace/dummylandapp/war/../gwt-unitCache.

And see that it *might* be related to [this bug with Debian packages](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=685587), which ultimately boil down to issues with `libgwt-dev-java`.

What's going on here, and what is `libgwt-dev-java`?

Comment: Also can replicate this, fresh 12.04 install, previous install was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve my error, it was related to the path to the gwt-unitcache.